# Cannot convert value of type ' ( ) ' to expected argument type 'Binding<C>'

Tags: generics, swiftui, foreach

### Problem

I got an error message "Cannot convert value of type '[Properties]' to expected argument type 'Binding" while using ForEach

```
    ScrollView {
        LazyVStack(alignment: .center) {
             ForEach(foodFilterResult[currentIndex], id: \.self) { // (Error occurred here)
                value in
                NavigationLink {
                    FoodInfoView(foodInfo: modelData.foodData.filter{$0.name.title.first!.text.content == value}.first!)
                } label: {
                    ZStack{
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                            .foregroundColor(.orange).opacity(0.06)
                            .frame(width: 350, height: 280)

                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("\(value)")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .padding(.bottom, -3)
                                .font(.system(size: 20).weight(.heavy))
                                .frame(width: 300, alignment: .leading)
```

### More Information

The foodFilterResult[currentIndex] (which is the data used in ForEach) has a type [Properties]

```
var foodFilterResult = foodFilter()

func foodFilter () -> [[Properties]] {
var western : [Properties] = []
var korean : [Properties] = []
var chinese : [Properties] = []
var japanese : [Properties] = []
var asian : [Properties] = []
var cafe : [Properties] = []
           
      ...

}
return [korean, western, chinese, japanese, asian, cafe]
```

}

### Properties

The struct "Properties" is a DTO for getting data from Notion DataBase

```
struct Properties: Codable, Equatable {

let imageFile: ImageFile
var id: IDClass
let propertiesDescription: Description
let transportation: People
let location, imageName: Description
let category, price: Category
let people: People
let name: Name
var isFavorite = false

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case imageFile, id
    case propertiesDescription = "description"
    case transportation, location, imageName, category, price, people, name
}
```

}

### Tries

I firstly searched ForEach and found that Data used in ForEach need toconform to RandomAccessCollection. But I don't know how to adjust it.

Can anybody help how to solve or access this kind of problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where, exactly, is the error? You may also what to rethink your data model since, as you are seeing, an array of arrays is a pain. With your set up, I would consider a Dict of type <String:Property> where String is the cuisine. Also, what kind of Notion database? It is difficult to suggest more.